# npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\...\package.json'

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm doing a tutorial on VueJS. I am completely new to this, so not enitrely sure what I am doing.
I followed all instructions, installed all packages, here is the check I made in terminal in VSCode:

```
PS C:\Users\...\Documents\Vue - Getting Started> node --version
v12.18.0
PS C:\Users\...\Documents\Vue - Getting Started> npm --version
6.14.5
PS C:\Users\...\Documents\Vue - Getting Started> vue --version
@vue/cli 4.4.1
```

However, whenever I try to `npm run serve` as it's shown in the tutorial, it shows an error stating that a `package.json` is missing:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\...\package.json'
```

I checked, and indeed, I don't have a file called `package.json` in my user folder. I only have a file called `package-lock.json`.

I also noticed, that on the tutorial video, the terminal has something like `1: node`, while in mine, I can see `1: powershell`. Here is the screenshot:

[screenshot from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEHyy.png)

What am I missing? Thank you

---

As suggested by El, I did `npm init` and created a `package.json` file in my project folder. Inside, I added the bit suggested by El. The whole `package.json` file now looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "package json",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "serve": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And I am now getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! package.json@1.0.0 serve: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the package.json@1.0.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Comment: For starting any JavaScript project you need to use `npm init` for making project configurations

Comment: Can you post link of the tutorial here?

Comment: @El. according to the error message, NodeJS tried to find `package.json` in another folder, not the project folder.

Comment: @dangxuanvuong98 "another folder" is the user root folder in Windows

Comment: @El. Yes, i know, but why NodeJS try to find `package.json` in root folder. Note that, the command is called from `C:\Users\...\Documents\Vue - Getting Started`.

Comment: @dangxuanvuong98 Yes, you are right. Julia please provide us the contents of your current directory by `ls` in powershell or `dir` command in CMD

Comment: @dangxuanvuong98 it's just index.html. and now I also added package.json as suggested in the anwser by El

Answer (score 6):

I think there's no need to explain Nodejs ENOENT error with such a self-explanatory error message: `no such file or directory` which simply means `index.js` or any file that you want to run with `npm` or `node` isn't in the current directory.
First you need to check to see if you are in the root of your project then in the root of your project you need to have a config file that is `package.json` for JavaScript(Nodejs, react, typescript and so on) projects.
So for making that config file you can use `npm init` command and it will ask you predefined questions about your projects.
for starting or serving your project you must have a script tag like this in your `package.json` file:

```
'scripts':{
  'serve': 'node index.js',
}
```

then you can use `npm run serve` command in the root of your project to run `serve` command of your `package.json` file.

In case of VueJS, which I am not familiar with, I think you have a `index.html` file in the root directory of your project and aslo as I know you have `vue` installed on your machine. I guess you need to replace `node index.js` with following command to serve your Vue application:

```
'scripts':{
  'serve': 'vue index.html',
}
```

and run `npm run serve`.

Comment: thanks - I created a `package.json` file in my project folder. now when I try to `npm run serve` I get the following: `npm ERR! missing script: serve`. Where do I put the script you mentioned? I just have a index.html file..

Comment: add it to your `package.json` file

Comment: Running into another problem, updating my original question.

Comment: You must have a `index.js` file too.

Comment: added an empty `index.js` file, now I get the following message (server doesn't start): `> package.json@1.0.0 serve C:\Users\....\Documents\Vue - Getting Started
> node index.js` and nothing else happens

Comment: Ok, I've got it. change the `"serve": "node index.js"` to `"serve": "vue index.html"` and let me know about the result

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with those commands:

```
// Locate to the folder, where the "node_modules" directory is stored

rm node_modules
npm i
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

deleted the project folder and  then creating vue project

```
vue create my-project
```

This is how it worked for me