# My react app does not start when I write npm start and get this error can anyone please help me I am new to react. I am using Acode(Editor) and termux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start, termux

npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path
 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2022-07-07T10_43_10_803Z-debug-0.log
~ $

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem's solution is written in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62235110/14387700). Though that was a different case(probably) and here you didn't explained your problem much in the description, but I think the error message: `no such file or directory` described everything which simply means `index.js` or any file that you want to run with `npm` or `node` isn't in the current directory.